# How many points can Folium Maps Hold?

Tags: javascript, python, html, gis, folium

I am working on a GIS mapping project that requires ~ a few million points to be plotted on a map. I have been looking into Folium and working with the marker cluster function. So far, I have not experienced many issues with a few hundred thousand points, but I would like to know if there are any better alternatives to Folium, or if there are any other methods that I should be using for further development.

I've looked into superclusters, but I don't know if those will be implementable. Ideally, I would end with a Python file that could generate an HTML file. As of now, I have been fetching data in Python from a Postgres database and loading this into a json that it inserted into a script for the HTML to make markers and cluster them.

Comment: If you wanted to stick with your current tooling, you could use something like `PostGIS` and then render the points for the current viewport the user is currently on instead of trying to render this all in one go.